# Is the regulator doing short circuit after enable?

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, ftdi

Is it my circuit/PCB doing a short circuit after enabling the regulator? See image. (I checked the connection physically and is fine.)

I don't understand why after enabling the regulator using the line `digitalWrite(4, HIGH)` (Arduino IDE 1.8.9 ATMega328P), the power supply or LED or I don't know what thing happens... And the code freezes or I don't know.

`digitalWrite(5, HIGH)` is pwr2 label for enable the simcom gprs IC.

I'm feeding my custom PCB with [FTDI board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZAPO.jpg). Other sketches work fine, but when I try to enable the regulator, the FTDI LEDs have lower intensity of the brightness and the code is not executed to the next line. If I comment the line, the code follows the normal execution.

My sketch worked fine by connecting the FTDI to another laptop through USB.

[image]

Comment: How much current does the simcom gprs module draw?  How much current can the 5V source from the FTDI module supply?

Comment: Current consumption rises to 2A in the transmit burst (no constant). Average for PCS_MODE 285mA. But starting I guess is not high current consumption.
If I active the regulator and no the simcom all is okay, and then If I power on the simcom manually using a wire from 5v to pwr2 the simcom start

Comment: Ups. I put a electrolytic capacitor 2200uF 16V between 5V and GND, then run again the sketch AND it is working fine again... SO it was a current problem I guess

Comment: 2A is more than USB can offer by itself, you know... THat's why you need a hefty buffer to "survive" the burst.

Comment: Yes I know, but in my old laptop I didnt need capacitor. Also I tried to connect directly the ftdi board to a 2A usb charging and also doesnt work. I check VCC of FTDI board is connected directly to usb port. I really dont understand.